# Como mostrar la hora y la fecha en un formulario modal utilizando la librería fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Estoy trabajando con la librería fullcalendar y el problema que me ha surgido en este momento es que al generar un formulario modal a partir del evento dayClick() no se refresca el día ni la hora seleccionada.
Simplemente queda guardado la hora y el dia que se selecciono la primera vez.

Dejo el código para que se entienda mejor

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     defaultView: 'agendaWeek',     
     header: {
         left: 'prev,next',
         center: 'title',
         right: 'agendaWeek'
        },
        editable: true,
   eventLimit: true,
   weekend: true,
    allDaySlot: false,
    minTime: '16:00:00',
    maxTime: '19:59:59',
    slotDuration: '00:20:00',
    dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
     var hora = date.format("h:mm:ss a");
     alert(hora);
     var dia = date.format("D MMM YY");
     var form = '<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">'+
         '<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">'+
          '<div class="modal-content">'+
           '<div class="modal-header">'+
            '<h4 class="modal-title text-center text-muted" id="myModalLabel">Seleccione el horario para el turno</h4>'+
           '</div>'+
           '<div class="modal-body">'+
            '<div class="form-group">'+
              '<label for="textDia" class="control-label col-md-3 text-left text-muted">Dia</label>'+
              '<div class="col-md-9">'+
                                       '<input type="text" id="textDia" class="form-control input-sm" name="textDia" onkeyup="" value="'+dia+'">'+
                                   '</div>'+
             '</div><br>'+
            '<div class="form-group">'+
              '<label for="textHora" class="control-label col-md-3 text-left text-muted">Hora</label>'+
              '<div class="col-md-9">'+
                                       '<input type="text" id="textHora" class="form-control input-sm" name="textHora" onkeyup="" value="'+hora+'">'+
                                   '</div>'+
             '</div><br>'+
           '</div>'+
           '<div class="modal-footer">'+
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>'+
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar cambios</button>'+
              '</div>'+
          '</div>'+
         '</div>'+
      '</div>';
   $('#ventanaModal').append(form);
    $('#myModal').modal('show'); 
      

    }
    
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container" id="calendar"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Has pensado en manpular el metodo nativo de JS? creas una variable nueva y le asignas el metodo Date()

Te pongo el codigo por aca:

```js
 function(date, jsEvent, view) {
            let d = new Date();
            let dia = d.getDate() + "/" + d.getMonth() + "/" + d.getFullYear(); // aca le modificas el formato del output <--
            let hora = d.getHours();
            var form = '<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">'+
                            '<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">'+
                                '<div class="modal-content">'+
                                    '<div class="modal-header">'+
                                        '<h4 class="modal-title text-center text-muted" id="myModalLabel">Seleccione el horario para el turno</h4>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                    '<div class="modal-body">'+
                                        '<div class="form-group">'+
                                            '<label for="textDia" class="control-label col-md-3 text-left text-muted">Dia</label>'+
                                            '<div class="col-md-9">'+
                                                '<input type="text" id="textDia" class="form-control input-sm" name="textDia" onkeyup="" value="'+ dia +'">'+
                                            '</div>'+
                                        '</div><br>'+
                                        '<div class="form-group">'+
                                            '<label for="textHora" class="control-label col-md-3 text-left text-muted">Hora</label>'+
                                            '<div class="col-md-9">'+
                                                '<input type="text" id="textHora" class="form-control input-sm" name="textHora" onkeyup="" value="'+hora+'">'+
                                            '</div>'+
                                        '</div><br>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                    '<div class="modal-footer">'+
                                        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>'+
                                        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar cambios</button>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</div>'+
                        '</div>';
            $('#ventanaModal').append(form);
        $('#myModal').modal('show');    
            

        }
```

Comment: La verdad que no, pero me gustaría solucionar primero este problema. Es decir que se actualice el dia y la hora cada vez que se  ejecute el método dayClick

Comment: esa funcion que esta ahi es la misma que tenias con las modificaciones que te indique,solo la colocas dentro de dayClick

Comment: El código HTML no debe estar dentro del JS. Busquen una solución más elegante chicos